# Why is my while() statement caught in an infinite loop?

Tags: c

I tried to write code to show any kind of sum_number (1,3,6,10,15,21,...) which has a specific number of divisions ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,c1=1,t=0,c2=1,gn=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(t!=n){
        t=0;
        gn=(c1*(c1+1)/2);
        while(c2<=gn){
            if(gn%c2==0){
                c2+=1;
                t+=1;
            }
            else c2+=1;
        }
        c1+=1;
        c2=1;
    }
    printf("%d", gn);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of 4 to be 6 or 2 to be 3 but there is no output!!!

Comment: What happens if you add a newline after the printing, like e.g. `printf("%d\n", gn);`? And have you tried to step through the code, statement by statement, in a debugger to see that it really does what you think it does?

Comment: No it doesn't work i think it gets stuck in the loop but it shouldn't. I go through the code step by step with an example of 4 and it should print 6 but it doesn't.

Comment: @ArshanDalili In which IDE you working actually with this? If not an IDE, reference your current environment.

Comment: can you please explain bit more about your problem statement

Comment: You are using `c2` uninitialized (`while(c2<=gn`).

Comment: @RobertS I'm working on codeblocks 17.12

Comment: @RohitSuthar I'm looking for the first number in sum of N numbers (1,3,6,10,15,21...) (n*(n+1)/2) which has a specific number of divisive.

Comment: @MathiasSchmid even initializing that would not help I tested that.

Comment: The condition of while-loop (`while(t!=n)`) will never become `false` for your example input values `2` and `4` and thus will loop endless. Are you sure you are using the right condition? I guess it should be `while(t<=n)` or `while(t<n)` which prints the expected values for your examples.

Comment: @ArshanDalili You said there is no output, which is impossible i think because you got at least one `printf()`statement `printf("%d", gn);` there, who should be getting executed. Can you please provide the output?

Comment: The edited code just works!!! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your outer while test condition. I ran your code, adding printf statements after each while for 'Outer loop' and 'Inner loop'. The execution results in this (just posting the beginning, but the pattern continues infinitely)

```
Outer while, t = 0, n = 4
Inner while, c2 = 1, gn = 1
Outer while, t = 1, n = 4
Inner while, c2 = 1, gn = 3
Inner while, c2 = 2, gn = 3
Inner while, c2 = 3, gn = 3
Outer while, t = 3, n = 4
Inner while, c2 = 1, gn = 6
Inner while, c2 = 2, gn = 6
Inner while, c2 = 3, gn = 6
Inner while, c2 = 4, gn = 6
Inner while, c2 = 5, gn = 6
Inner while, c2 = 6, gn = 6
Outer while, t = 7, n = 4
Inner while, c2 = 1, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 2, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 3, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 4, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 5, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 6, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 7, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 8, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 9, gn = 10
Inner while, c2 = 10, gn = 10
Outer while, t = 11, n = 4
```

Your logic is causing the inner loop to continue for more and more loops - it takes longer and longer for c to approach gn. But the showstopper is how t increments -- for an input of 4, it vaults past n, so you don't exit that loop.

Comment: the reason for infinite loop was that 't' needed to be 0 before restarting the loop